# Google play console is showing that my app took background location permission but my app didn't

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-permissions

I created an android app with flutter. I didn't take any background location permission in my app but when I try to upload my app to Google play store it shows me I took background location permission.

Here is the screenshot of my manifest file:

[image]

.

And here is the screenshot of play console where it shows me that I took background location permission:

[image]

.

And here is the list of all pub packages of my app:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're using a library that has the location permission. write the code at the bottom of this post, in your manifest to remove the permissions. **But attention**, probably by doing this action, your app gets into trouble. Test your app before publishing, or, find and remove or replace the library that using location permission.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It removed that unwanted permission.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I uploaded a new application on google play console.
Here are the steps that u need to follow in order to successfully publish your application:

**Very Important Note:** Keep in mind that u need to upload the APK in the same track in which it got rejected.

-Go to google play console and click on you desired App.

-If your App is rejected in a very first release(No accepted live release) than u have to check for internal testing tab, **alpha testing (closed testing)** and open testing apps etc. in left tabs panel.

-You can check you APK permission list in App bundle explorer tab in left tab panel in Google play console.

-Go to a corresponding track probably in **alpha test (closed testing)** where your rejected APK is, And upload a new APK on that track (not into publish tab, that's a separate track).

-after uploading new APK on same track you will see an option to disable the old apk version in which you have location permission problem. Disable it and pause old track.

-Now go to app content from left tab panel, scroll and look for Sensitive app permissions' and click on manage.

-On next page under location permission, click on manage.

-You will see the question :Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 (Pie) or older (SDK level 28 or lower)?

-Select **"No"** in options.And you are Good to Go,

-Double check permission list from app bundle explorer again.

Hope it would help you.